# How to set content type of an AWS S3 file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mime, pre-signed-url

First URL is presigned. Then with PUT message the gif file is uploaded. Content-Type is set both when presigning and also in PUT message, but in AWS interface gif type is not visible. Why?

PUT request header:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,nl;q=0.9,hu;q=0.8,de;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 10912652
Content-Type: image/gif. // <---------------
Host: t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
x-amz-acl: public-read
```

[image]

If image is uploaded from web interface, gif type is visible.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Content-type` is [S3 metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html#SysMetadata). So to change it, you have to modify the metadata properties of your objects.